# Visual studio 2022 breakpoint issue

Tags: visual-studio-2022

In some of my code breakpoint is not hitting.
For eg in below image line no 2191 and 2192 breakpoint is hitting but from 2193 to 2204 breakpoint is not hitting

[image: In line no 2191 and 2192 breakpoint is hitting but from 2193 to 2204 breakpoint is not hitting]

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: what happens if you break on 2191 and just single step further? Does it work? Maybe an exception occurs on line 2192 if `.FirstOrDefault` returns null?

Comment: @PawełŁukasik But its going to 2192 line fine. If FirstOrDefault  returns null than it should throw exception on 2192 line and go to catch

Comment: Please post a [mre], (and full source code), otherwise a lot of guessing can be done.  (Please also read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [How do I ask a question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) )

Comment: Did you read: [Tutorial: Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022)?  It's only a 21 minutes read, and it might help you answer your own question.

Comment: @user2884940 I don't see any try-catch on this image so why should it catch anything?